# Unable to play .flv video on UI WebView in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, https, uiwebview

I am working on an iOS app, in this app I have to stream a video on UIwebview. When I try to stream mp4 format video then it is working, but when video format is .flv then it does not work at all. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't support flash.  Best bet is re-encode the video to mp4 on the server side.